# Cannot connect wifi on Ubuntu 18.04 (Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01))

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, broadcom

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP DV6 Laptop. I got

> No Wifi Adapter Found

I tried some instructions but they were unsuccessful.

[This is my wireless info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YwXCd8FPkk/).

How can I fix it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you. I installed it successfully. However, now I got the signal wifi changing from high to weak, weak to high continuity. How should I do?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question. Consider asking a new question with necessary details.